# Can and can't in AmE

Tags: american-english

Is it true that when pronouncing "I can do that" in American English when the "can" is stressed, there is a slight delay between the "can" and "do" and the primary stress is usually on I, while in "I can't do that" the primary stress is on "can't" and there is no delay?

Talking about cases with only one stress.

Comment: You should edit your question to be clearer. If you stress *can*, you don't stress *I* (which is what I think you mean, but not what you've said).

Comment: *I can't do that* can take different stresses: compare ***I** can't do that, but you can*; *I **can't** do that. I don't know how*; *I can't do **that**, but I can do something better*. Even the *do* can take the stress but a clear example is harder to write down

Comment: The stress goes on the word that the speaker most wishes to emphasise *in the specific context*. So *any* of the words in *I can do that* might carry heavy stress, depending on whether the speaker wishes to emphasise the ***he*** (as opposed to someone else) can do it, that he ***can*** (as opposed to being unable to) do it, etc. It's a bit contrived, but perfectly possible, to emphasise that you can ***do*** something (as opposed to simply *talk* about doing it, for example).

Comment: One might very well stress "that".

Comment: There's no "delay". The vowel is shorter in *can't* than in *can*, because it's before a non-voiced consonant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's not quite on the button there. In an unmarked pronunciation new information will be stressed and old information will be unstressed and the nucleus will go on the last piece of new information. When we use contrastive stress, we can pick out things that would normally be unstressed to contrast them with another salient idea or individual. We can even do this with individual syllables within words which are not normally stressed. But none of this in any way means that stress within sentences is not predictable or organised according to principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an unmarked pronunciation (so therefore a pronunciation with no contrastive stress) the two sentences would be pronounced as follows, where an apostrophe ['] premarks a stressed syllable:

- /aɪ kən 'du: ðæt/ <sup>*I can do that*</sup>
- /aɪ 'kænʔ 'du: ðæt/ <sup>*I can't do that*</sup>

The white space between the words above doesn't indicate any sort of gap or silence. There is no pause here between the [n] in /kən/ and the [d] in /du:/ in the first example. Notice that if there is no contrastive stress, the pronoun *I* is unstressed.